# Introducing Ajax support in a MyFaces (JSF) + Tomahawk application

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, frameworks

we have a project where we are using **MyFaces + Tomahawk**, recently I have been requested to provide enhancements to many of the existing screens by using **AJAX** and provide functionality such as partial refresh. As I see, **Tomahawk's components don't have special support for Ajax**, so it may be a lot of work to hack Tomahawk in order to use Ajax.

Now, I have seen that there are **other frameworks such as Trinidad, ajax4jsf, RichFaces, etc**. I'm specially interested in **Trinidad** since it is also a MyFaces project and it has **built-in Ajax support**, but I'm not still convinced about Trinidad since the other frameworks also have very promising features.

Considering that I have a MyFaces+Tomahawk application, what move would you suggest to take in order to introduce Ajax support? Hack with Tomahawk or directly with JSF/MyFaces? Use Trinidad? Use/Add a different framework?

**EDIT**: I just read about **Tobago** which is also part of Apache MyFaces, and I would like to add the following question: How does Tobago compare to Trinidad? To the other frameworks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for richfaces. It is a de-facto standard for jsf ajax handling. The principles of richfaces influenced JSF 2.0 ajax support.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using RichFaces, and I have to say that it is awesome!